# Calculate the union of many intervals

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to obtain the union of many (more than 2) intervals:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3),
             interval=c(
               new_interval(ymd("2001-01-01"), ymd("2002-01-01")),
               new_interval(ymd("2001-01-01"), ymd("2004-01-01")),
               new_interval(ymd("2001-02-01"), ymd("2002-01-01"))
               ))
df
#   id                       interval
# 1  1 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC
# 2  2 2001-01-01 UTC--2004-01-01 UTC
# 3  3 2001-02-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC

lubridate::union(lubridate::union(df$interval[1], df$interval[2]),
                 df$interval[3])
# [1] 2001-01-01 UTC--2004-01-01 UTC
```

That's the correct result.

But why `lubridate::union` does not work with `Reduce`?

```
Reduce(lubridate::union, df$interval )
# [1] 31536000 94608000 28857600
```

The intervals objects seem to get converted to numeric too son (before applying the `union`).

Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909358/maintain-attributes-of-objects-of-class-lubridate-interval

Comment: It would be great that any of the mantainers of the `lubridate` package could improve it to permit using the `Reduce` function.   I registered a new issue:  https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/348

Comment: Just for future reference.  If you open a github issue while the question is still open, please make note of it in this question so people can easily become aware of it.  I answered this without seeing the link to your github issue, which had already been closed before I submitted my answer.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is not `Reduce()`. Rather, it is  `as.list()`, which is applied to `x` inside `Reduce()` when the provided `x` argument is not a list to begin with.  The relevant lines are lines 8 and 9 in `Reduce()`, shown below.

```
head(Reduce, 9)
# ...                                                           
# 8      if (!is.vector(x) || is.object(x))                   
# 9          x <- as.list(x)
```

A quick check of the `if()` condition confirms this.

```
!is.vector(df$interval) || is.object(df$interval)
# [1] TRUE
```

Therefore `as.list()` is used on `df$interval` in your call to `Reduce()`,  which means `df$interval` becomes

```
as.list(df$interval)
# [[1]]
# [1] 31536000
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 94608000
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 28857600
```

before any important operations in `Reduce()` occur (actually this is the most important operation for our purposes).  This makes the `Reduce()` output sensible; it returns all three since they are unique.

If you really need to use `Reduce()` you can bypass the list check and construct your own list first, using a `for()` loop (as `lapply()` also will not work).  Then we can feed that to `Reduce()` and get the proper desired output.

```
x <- vector("list", length(df$interval))
for(i in seq_along(x)) x[[i]] <- df$interval[i]

Reduce(lubridate::union, x)
# [1] 2001-01-01 UTC--2004-01-01 UTC
```

But it would probably be best to write an `as.list()` method for the *Interval* class and put it at the top of your script.  We can use the same code as above.

```
as.list.Interval <- function(x, ...) {
    out <- vector("list", length(x))
    for(i in seq_along(x)) out[[i]] <- x[i]
    out
}

Reduce(lubridate::union, df$interval)
# [1] 2001-01-01 UTC--2004-01-01 UTC
```

Also note that you can do this another way, by grabbing the starting slots and using `int_end()`.

```
interval(min(slot(df$interval, "start")), max(int_end(df$interval)))
# [1] 2001-01-01 UTC--2004-01-01 UTC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @richard-scriven.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the `Reduce` case, but I would do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df  %>% 
  mutate(interval = str_trim(str_replace_all(interval, "(--|UTC)", " ")),
         int_start = word(interval), 
         int_end = word(interval, -1)) %>% 
  summarise(interval = str_c(min(int_start), 
                             max(int_end), 
                             sep = "--"))
# result
                interval
1 2001-01-01--2004-01-01
```

Comment: So, you have a 7-line code which provide the same result that the one liner `lubridate::union`?

Comment: @Pascal You do not have to like my answer.

Comment: Anyway it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Pascal it is actually 1 line :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been just solved on the `lubridate` package
https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/348